# Javascript: how to move a prototype inside a namespace Class?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I built a map with google V3 api and everything works fine, now i need to merge my code with someone else and i have to create a namespace for all my functions..

so, given my class
 `MY.myMap = Class.create(...)`

i'm "translating" my own code from

```
function boxOn(index) {
    this.objId.find('#location' + index).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: bgColorOn,
        color: colorOn
    },
    300);
}
```

to

```
   MY.myMap = Class.create(

           boxOn: function(index) {
                this.objId.find('#location' + index).stop().animate({
                    backgroundColor: this.bgColorOn,
                    color: this.colorOn
                },
                300);
            },

    *etc..etc..etc..*

)
```

etc...this is ok so far... but i have prototype coded like (google map code)

```
InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

InfoBox.prototype.remove = function() {
    if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
        this.div_ = null;
    }
};

InfoBox.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.createElement();
    if (!this.div_) return;
    var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
    if (!pixPosition) return;
    this.div_.style.width = this.width_ + "px";
    this.div_.style.left = (pixPosition.x + this.offsetHorizontal_) + "px";
    this.div_.style.height = this.height_ + "px";
    this.div_.style.top = (pixPosition.y + this.offsetVertical_) + "px";
    this.div_.style.display = 'block';
};
```

how to I write this objects??